# Symfony2 bundle configuration parameters

Tags: symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

My team develops a very large e-commerce project. Up to now, we had something like 40 configuration parameters in that bundle and I didn't know their final relations nor had a way to structure them properly, so we ended up using the standard parameters structure in the `app/config.yml` file. **But**, somewhere along the way I decided to move the config to the semantic configuration structure - so I can validate it, have a clean structure, easily extend it by means of bundle inheritance and so on.

The problem is I can't import our bundle parameters to another bundle config, now.

**Here's what I could do before:**

```
(...)
parameters:
    company.bundle.email.user: user@domain.com
    company.bundle.email.pass: @MyBeAUtiFULpA55w0Rd!
(...)

swiftmailer:
    (...)
    username: %company.bundle.email.user%
    password: %company.bundle.email.pass%
```

**Here's what I'm trying to do now and it doesn't work at all:**

```
(...)
company_bundle:
    (...)
    settings:
        (...)
        mailer:
            (...)
            user: user@domain.com
            pass: @MyBeAUtiFULpA55w0Rd!
 (...)

 swiftmailer:
     (...)
     username: %company_bundle.settings.mailer.user%
     password: %company_bundle.settings.mailer.pass%

 (...)
```

Of course the `company_bundle` node contains the semantic configuration, processed by the DIC and defined in `Company\Bundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php`.

All I end up with for now is the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]                       
You have requested a non-existent parameter "company_bundle.settings.mailer.user".
```

So the question is: how to make my bundle parameters accessible in another bundle configuration parameters (I've already taken care of including my bundle configuration *always* before the Swiftmailer bundle)?

NOTICE: Swiftmailer bundle configuration is shown here only for demonstration purposes, I want to be able to reuse my bundle parameters across some other bundles as well.

**What's the motivation behind that?**

Well I want our product to be configured by a person who doesn't know Symfony well - so she must be able to open our bundle config file and just tweak the parameters, which will then be used in some Symfony bundles we use. So I want *all* application configuration to be accessible in our bundle's semantic conf, since I'd want not to expose the whole configuration to that person (I've already divided everything into separate config files, one of them containing the configuration for our bundle, the rest - for all the other ones).

So, is what I'm asking even possible?

Comment: Bundles cannot share configuration values. If you want this, you would need to modify the way configuration works. The way I would suggest is have a single file with `parameters` in there and then using those values in your "real" config files where you need them.

Answer (score 1):

As the parameters are to be modified in each installation (they probably differ at least  between development and production environments), so (as Sgoettschkes said in comment) external file is the best solution.

In Symfony2 by default place for such parameters is **parameters.yml** file located in app/config/ dir.

In standard installation you can find for example such entries:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    (...)
```

These params are used in config.yml this way:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        (...)
```

So you can define your params (in **parameters.yml**):

```
parameters:
    (...)
    company_bundle_email_user: user@domain.com
    company_bundle_email_pass: @MyBeAUtiFULpA55w0Rd!
```

and use them (in **config.yml**):

```
swiftmailer:
    (...)
    username: %company_bundle_email_user%
    password: %company_bundle_email_pass%
```